# Can't get Apple Hardware Test to work

Tags: hardware, apple-hardware-test

So I'm trying to run the Apple Hardware Test. I start the computer up and hold "D". It boots into OS X like a normal startup. So, I plug in the Ethernet and hold option-D to do the AHT from the Internet. It tells me "Apple Hardware Test does not support this machine".

So, I try to install the "iMac EFI Update 1.8" from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1493 (which is for my iMac model, which is a iMac (Mid 2010)), but it says "This software is not supported on your system." I also tried the later version, v1.9, from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1498 but it isn't for my iMac and so I get the same error.

I also tried putting in my DVD 1 for my iMac, then starting up by holding both "D" and "option-D", but neither booted AHT from the DVD.

So now I'm stuck. What should I do now?

Comment: Do firmware updates like these EFI updates give that "This software is not supported" message if you run them on a system where they're already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I finally got it working by inserting DVD 2 rather than DVD 1. It clearly indicated on the DVD that it has Apple Hardware Test, which I missed the first time. This could be useful to those who have a similar problem to mine, I suppose.

Comment: Brilliant!! I've been trying to get into AHT for 2 days now and made the same mistake, popped in the second disc and all done in 15 minutes - marvellous!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another mac? Can you boot the problematic machine in Target Mode (boot holding the T key). Connect to the other mac and run system utilities (Disk, etc) from there.

What is the problem with your computer that requires you to run AHT?

Hope this helps.